# How to organize multiple arrays in one class?

Tags: java, class

This will eventually allow a user to look up a book by using a two digit number. The title however will only output if you input the correct number. Details about code wherever important info is written...

Basically a sum of the program you input a number (refNum) which is matches up correctly to predetermined values of binarySearch array...will output a book title.

```
   class books {

        String refNum, title;

        books (String _refNum, String _title) {
            refNum = _refNum = enterNumberField.getText(); //grab inputted #(continues...)
```

(continued) to compare
 with numbers stored in array, the # must equal # in binarySearch array which if equal, will 
 proper title to output. Aka reNum = 4 (also binarySearch[0]) must equal title[0] to    output "Harry Potter"

```
            int refNum[] = new int[2];

            refNum[0] = 4;
            refNum[1] = 6;
            refNum[2] = 10;

            int binarySearch[] = new int[2];

            binarySearch[0] = 4;
            binarySearch[1] = 6;
            binarySearch[2] = 10;

            String title[] = new String[2];

            title[0] = "Harry Potter";
            title[1] = "Chrysalids";
            title[2] = "Lord of the Flies";
       }
   }
```

This will be for the binary search as it uses the inputed number to find if it matches up with anything, and if it does it outputs the corresponding title.

```
public static Boolean binarySearch(String [ ] A, int left, int right, String V){
         int middle;
         refNum ++;
         if (left > right) {
             return false;
         }

         middle = (left + right)/2;
         int compare = V.compareTo(A[middle]);
         if (compare == 0) {
             return true;
         }
         if (compare < 0) {
             return binarySearch(A, left, middle-1, V);
         } else {
             return binarySearch(A, middle + 1, right, V);
         }
     }
```

eventually I'll add the code which outputs this, but first I need to learn how to organize the arrays in the class and actual search, hopefully I've explained this in a way you understand my goal...so any ideas?

Comment: Is there an SO category for **Incomprehensible question**?

Comment: Are you trying to search for an item in an array of `book` objects, sorted by `refNum`?

Comment: Yes, the ultimate goal is to search for the title (aka the item) of a book

Comment: Do you have to code your own binary search algorithm? An alternative would be to use a [`HashMap<Integer, String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 1):

In general you should avoid several arrays in one class with this equal indexes thing. This s rather done by an array of book:

```
public class Book {
  private int refNum;
  private String name;

  public Book(int refNum, String name) {
    this.refNum = refNum;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getRefNum() {
    return refNum;
  }

  public void setRefNum(int refNum) {
    this.refNum = refNum;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// a comparator allows ordering to an arbitrary row
public RefNumOrder implements Comparator<Book> {
  public int compare(Book b1, Book b2) {
    return b1.getRefNum() - b2.getRefNum();
  }
}

public class Books {
  private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
  public Books() {
     books.add(new Book(..);
     ..
  }
  public Book getByRefNum( int refNum) {
    Collections.sort(books, new RefNumOrder());
    int index =  Collections.binarySearch(book, new RefNumOrder());
    if (index >= 0) return books.get(index);
    return null;
  }
}
```

This way you can easily lookup for any row without the need of handling several arrays.

Comment: This is great! However, how would I access any values (say refNum) if it is not recognized outside of the public class "Book"?

Comment: The class `Book` have the method `getRefNum()` and `setRefNum(..)` implemented already. So if you don't understand the above code then you might need to read more about Class and Access modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You know, you can just use a Map and do lookups.